# encryption using protectedData.protect in windows phone 7.1

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone 7 application in which I send encrypted data to a webservice that decrypts it. I'm using the `protectedData.protect` which is only working properly as long as I am encrypting and decrypting from my application (for testing only); once I use the webservice the behaviour changes.

This is the code from the webservice:

```vb
If Flag = False Then ' Decrypt
    Dim ProtectedPinByte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
    Dim PinByte2 As Byte() = ProtectedData.Unprotect(ProtectedPinByte, Nothing, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
    password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte2, 0, PinByte2.Length)
    Return Bll.Utilites.EncryptDecryptStr(True, password) 'Encrypts using another algorithm
Else ' Encrypt
    EncPassword = Bll.Utilites.EncryptDecryptStr(False, password) 'decrypts  from another algorithm
    Dim PinByte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncPassword)
    Dim ProtectedPinByte As Byte() = ProtectedData.Protect(PinByte, Nothing, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedPinByte, 0, ProtectedPinByte.Length)
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain more what happens? When does this work, and when does it not work? When it doesn't work, what output do you get?

Comment: When i run the encrypting and decrypting functions from my application it works correctly, and i do that only for testing the encrypt/decrypt functions.  But when i encrypt through my application and send the encrypted string to the webservice,the webservice doesn't decrypt properly. and this is the real scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as the ProtectedData class on Windows Phone uses device credentials to encrypt the data, it can only be decrypted on that device.

> In Silverlight for Windows Phone, both the user and machine
>   credentials are used to encrypt or decrypt data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.96).aspx

Comment: well, this explains it!! am using an alternative now but its REALLY important to know, Thanks Will :)